# What's the difference between create new instance and use same final instance of HttpClient when it comes to request the same site repeatedly?

Tags: java, httpclient

When I used HttpClient(4.x) to request same site like 1000 times, shared one final instance of client would be super slow response or fail(time-out, 500...) after 50 or 40 times, **BUT** it worked just fine when I created new instance of HttpClient for each request, about 98% of success rate.

I searched a lot about how HttpClient works? most of the answers says there's connection pool in HttpClient, and it will reuse the connection so that some cookies from last req may be cached and loaded by next req, is that the possible reason?